# Sticky right side nav using angular material

Tags: css, angular-material

I am trying to get a fixed right sidebar using angular material along with a fixed toolbar on the top. I seem to be missing something due to which it doesnt seem to work at all. I have tried to make a pen out of it, please let me know how to fix it.
Following is my md-content code

```
<md-content flex class='md-padding' layout="column">
    <md-card ng-repeat = "card in cards">
      {{card.title}}
      {{card.text}}
    </md-card>
    <md-sidenav flex md-component-id="right" md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-z2">
        <md-content layout="column">
            <div flex>
               <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
            </div>
            <div flex>
               <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
</md-content>
```

`

http://codepen.io/viggy_prabhu/pen/xVvQzr

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I set the sidenav and the content to be in layout row. Removed the `flex` attribute from the md-sidenav and instead distributed it into a 1/3 and 2/3 layout [flex="33" and flex="66"].

```
<md-content layout="row">
  <md-sidenav md-component-id="right" md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-z2" flex="33">
    <md-content layout="column">
      <div flex>
        <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
      </div>
      <div flex>
        <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
      </div>
      <div flex>
        <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
      </div>
      <div flex>
        <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-content>
  </md-sidenav>
  <md-content flex="66">
  <md-card ng-repeat="card in cards">
    {{card.title}} {{card.text}}
  </md-card>
  </md-content>
</md-content>
```

Comment: This is almost good except that it is creating a scroll bar in the content region rather than a scroll bar for the whole page. Is there someway I can fix that. I have modified the codepen with the changes you suggested. http://codepen.io/viggy_prabhu/pen/xVvQzr

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-app="materialApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout='column' layout-fill>
    <md-toolbar class='md-medium-tall'>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <span>Fixed to Top</span>
        <span flex></span>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content class='md-padding' layout="row">
      <div layout="column" flex>
        <md-card ng-repeat="card in cards">
          {{card.title}} {{card.text}}
        </md-card>
      </div>
      <md-sidenav flex=20 md-component-id="right" md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-z2" layout-fill>
        <md-content style="padding-top:5%; height: 200px" layout="column">
          <div flex>
            <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
          </div>
          <div flex>
            <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
          </div>
          <div flex>
            <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
          </div>
          <div flex>
            <md-button href="http://google.com"> Button </md-button>
          </div>
        </md-content>
      </md-sidenav>
    </md-content>
  </div>
</body>
```

Added a div around the md-card repeat and placed the md-sidenav next to it.
Also removed the layout from the body tag. This allows the side-nav to flex to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this did remove the scrollbar but it removed the fixed toolbar and even sidenav bar isnt fixed. I tried it on the codepen by updating it. http://codepen.io/viggy_prabhu/pen/xVvQzr

Comment: Oh sorry change the body tag to the following to make the navbar stay fixed since it is the parent who decides that property
`<body ng-app="materialApp" layout="column" flex>`
To make the sidenav sticky you will need to add some css elements. Dont think angular material provides that out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

you can try using $mdSticky service from angular material

```
(function() {
  angular.module('example', ['ngMaterial']);
})();

 (function() {
  angular.module('example').directive('sticky', Sticky);

    Sticky.$inject = [ '$mdSticky' ];

    function Sticky($mdSticky) {
        return {
            restrict : 'A',
            link : function(scope, element) {
                $mdSticky(scope, element);
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

codepen example https://codepen.io/mckenzielong/pen/LpyYME

tutorial can be found here:
https://www.coditty.com/code/angular-material-how-to-make-custom-elements-sticky-using-mdsticky